# Liquibase include external changelogFile

Tags: database, spring-boot, liquibase, changeset, changelog

I want to include external changelogFile in liquibase using springboot,
my file **db.changelog-master.xml** call external changeset in E: partition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">

    <include file="E:/00-PBI/PBI_105364/test-jar/db/changelog/V0_changelog_CREER_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTEMENT.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Then I got this message:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
```

is there anyone who can tell me whay i can't include this changeset? Thanx

Comment: Make sure your external file is include into your ClassPath atr tyhe moment you run the app.

Comment: That sounds as if the included changeLog contains something invalid. Btw: I would always use relative paths to include changelogs

Comment: Hello Zorglube, thank you for your reply, where is the locate of classPath ?

Comment: In fact, my jar is next to the V0_changelog_CREER_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTEMENT.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the path

```
/db/changelog/V0_changelog_CREER_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTEMENT.xml
```

Now it works :)